# How can I save attachments on InfoPath form to spreadsheet?

Tags: infopath

I need to save attachments submitted with the infopath form (for future reference) either on a spreadsheet or other format on a shared drive.

Comment: Can you please give more context? What version of SharePoint? Is this InfoPath on a workflow or on a list form? Where do you want to save the attachments? Are you doing this with SharePoint Designer, Visual Studio, Web UI, etc.? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Attachments are base 64 encoded and stored within the XML of the InfoPath form. I have used a Nintex workflow in the past to extract the attachments via workflow and send them in an email.

You'll likely need to write an event receiver to extract the attachments and store them where necessary.